# How to setup a y/n loop in java?

Tags: java

I have a program that is a palindrome checker that takes an input reverses it and checks if the original input is equal to the reverse. I'm trying to get a y/n loop inside of the program to check if the user wants to enter another palindrome. This is my code:

```
  public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String controller = "y";
    do {

        System.out.println("Enter a palindrome!");
        String input = scan.nextLine();
        String original = input;
        input = input.replaceAll("\\s", "");
        int len = input.length();
        char[] charArray = new char[len];
        char[] charArray2 = new char[len];

        for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
            charArray2[i] = input.charAt(i);
        }
        for(int j = 0; j < len; j++){
            charArray[j] = charArray2[len-1-j];
        }
        String palindrome = new String(charArray);
        if(palindrome.equals(input)){
            System.out.println(palindrome);
            System.out.println(original + " is a palindrome!\nWould you like to test another palindrome? (y/n)");
        }else{
            System.out.println(palindrome);
            System.out.println(original + " is not a palindrome!\nWould you like to test another palindrome? (y/n)");

        }
        scan.next(controller);

    }while(controller.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));

    }
```

This is the output I get:

```
Enter a palindrome!
was it a cat i saw
wasitacatisaw
was it a cat i saw is a palindrome!
Would you like to test another palindrome? (y/n)
y
Enter a palindrome!

 is a palindrome!
Would you like to test another palindrome? (y/n)
y
Enter a palindrome!

 is a palindrome!
Would you like to test another palindrome? (y/n)
y
Enter a palindrome!

 is a palindrome!
Would you like to test another palindrome? (y/n)
y
Enter a palindrome!

 is a palindrome!
Would you like to test another palindrome? (y/n)
y
Enter a palindrome!

 is a palindrome!
Would you like to test another palindrome? (y/n)
y
```

I can't figure out how to get it to wait for another entry and test that one instead. Any help would be great.

Comment: Maybe try `scan.nextLine(controller);`

Comment: replace `scan.next(controller)` with `controller = scan.nextLine().trim()`. `scan.next(controller)` is not assigning `controller` to `scan.next()` and `controller = scan.next()` would not consume the new-line character after the user enters `y` and thus the next call to `scan.nextLine()` just returns an empty string.

Comment: You're an absolute legend thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok i reworked your code a bit and tbh you werent far off.
[Here is a pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/nrzqryUg) with my code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String checker = "y"; //set checker to ensure the first cycle

    while(checker.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) { // check for correct phrase
        System.out.println("Enter a string to check!"); // inital message
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);        // read first line
        String input = reader.nextLine();
        if (isPalindrome(input)) {                      // check input for palindrome
            System.out.println(input + " is a Palindrome!");
        } else {
            System.out.println(input + " is not a Palindrome!");
        }
        System.out.println("Do you want to enter another string? y/n");
        checker = reader.nextLine();                    // set checker to response for next cycle
    }
    System.out.println("Ok bye :)");                    // death message
}


private static boolean isPalindrome(String s){
    String reverse = "";                            // create string for later comparison

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        reverse+=s.trim().charAt(s.length()-i-1);   // reverse the string
    }
    return reverse.equalsIgnoreCase(s);             // return boolean ignoring case
}
```

I really didnt change that much:

- I check the palindrome in a function for better readablility
- Used Strings instead of char[]. Its generally better practice handling userinput and general text that way.

EDIT:
my output:

```
Enter a string to check!
hey
hey is not a Palindrome!
Do you want to enter another string? y/n
y
Enter a string to check!
brb
brb is a Palindrome!
Do you want to enter another string? y/n
n
Ok bye :)

Process finished with exit code 0
```